# How to propagate resolved html value to component

Tags: angular

**Scenario**:

I have html table in angular template.  One of the columns is formulated as shown below:

```
    <td>
        Customer purchased as of {{element.date1}} and returned as of {{element.date2}}.
    </td>
```

Now, the table can have several rows each row can conditionally have similar/different data stitched from static text and element member variables.

**Problem/Need:** I have a need to sort based on resolved values.  I will be able to do it using a custom framework method if i can get hand on the resolved column cell value inside component code.

**Question:**
Is there a way to inject resolved column cell [eg: "Customer purchased as of 01/01/2020 and returned as of 02/20/2020."] value into a component member array?

Comment: Is it in ngFor? If yes, you can sort the array with Javascript / Pipe when you need

Comment: This is not for ngFor.  This of this as a material table. But, we use an internally developed framework to build html tables.  A custom function which can view table cell value can determine how it can be sorted if it has handle on the column value.

Comment: Please add more code, how you are implementing the grid, the template you are using ...etc. Using slackblitz for a demo will be better too